# Thymeleaf can't find JAR file

Tags: java, thymeleaf

So my Thymeleaf project directory looks like this right now:

```
WEB-INF
   jars
      print.jar
   templates
      label.html
      print.jar
```

The `label.html` page calls the Java Applet `print.jar` to print labels to a thermal printer from the browser:

```
<embed 
   name="LabelPrint"
   type="application/x-java-applet"
   width="0" height="0" 
   archive="print.jar"
   codebase="@{/jars}"
   code="qz.PrintApplet.class" 
/>
```

And the app can't find the JAR file:

```
16:37:20.370 ERROR f.a.controllers.ErrorController - Error: HTTP 404 -
```

Thinking that it's having trouble finding the `/jars` directory, I tried placing `print.jar` right alongside `label.html` in the `/templates` directory, and removed the "codebase" attribute from my `<embed>` tag:

```
<embed 
   name="LabelPrint"
   type="application/x-java-applet"
   width="0" height="0" 
   archive="print.jar"
   code="qz.PrintApplet.class" 
/>
```

And now it looks like Thymeleaf is trying load it as a page:

```
16:39:32.287 ERROR o.s.b.w.s.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/print.jar] due to exception [Index: 0, Size: 0]
```

This embed tag was working before I converted the application to using Thymeleaf.  Is there a way to get Thymeleaf to find the JAR file, and treat it as a JAR file?

Comment: The `WEB-INF` folder isn't readable with a regular web request.  The only reason you can see label.html is presumably you have a `@Controller` that is returning the contents.  If you want print.jar to be readable, it needs to be in a resources folder and not under WEB-INF.

Comment: @Metroids Thanks, that fixed it.  Moved the JAR file outside of WEB-INF (under webapp).  You're a life saver!